# Merging rows in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big .csv file, and I needed to group products with the same name based on ordered quantity, which I have done through groupby(). However, I need to use all 7 of my columns in my file, but after joining the rows, only the qty_ordered and name_hash are left, the rest of my columns disappear. Is there any way to keep all 7 of my columns in my dataframe while joining rows based on name_hash and qty_ordered ?
this is my code:

```
   import pandas as pd
   data = pd.read_csv('in/tables/sales-order-item.csv')
   data = data.groupby('qty_ordered')['name_hash'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

The output of this is name_hash and qty_ordered columns combined, but I need to keep the rest of my columns as well. Any ideas on how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have 20 rows in your original dataframe, when grouped by `qty_ordered` it may have only 10 unique values of `qty_ordered`.

What will be your other column values for the 10 unique values of `qty_ordered`? You have that figured for the column `name_hash`. If you know what to do with other columns similarly, you could use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html).

For example if you want the same agg as ' '.join for `name_hash`, then you could do

```
data.groupby('qty_ordered', as_index = False).agg(' '.join)
```

which will do the same operation  ' '.join for all columns.

Comment: thanks, it worked, although I lost 3 of my columns for some reason, only 4 joined itselves. Must be something with the data.

Comment: If you add example data, and desired output in your question you will get some answers.